# getting a UILabels image

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to get an image that corresponds to the current contents of a UILabel that I can then use and manipulate as if it were a UIImage?  For instance, lets say I use the modeStartMessageLabel UILabel in my code to display a message that I sometimes change on the fly.  Now let's imagine that I want to capture what the modeStartMessageLabel currently looks like, and then use that image in some specialized image processing that I use.  In those algorithms, I duplicate images and morph their positions into various shapes.

I think it would be fun and artful to be able to treat the contents of a label as if it were just like the  myArt.png file in my bundle.

```
UILabel  * modeStartMessageLabel;

UIImageView *myArt = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myArt.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UIImage *)getImageFromLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    UIImage *imageFromLabel;
    CGSize size = label.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 2);
    [label.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    imageFromLabel = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageFromLabel;
}
```

Comment: Probably want to use scale of `0` so it works on both retina and non-retina devices.

Comment: This solution worked well for me.  I just had to make sure the labels alpha was not zero when I got the image.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage image;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (label.bounds.size);
[label drawViewHierarchyInRect:label.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext ();
```

This only works in iOS 7, and is super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works with UILabel, but I can't see why it wouldn't.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(label.bounds.size);
[[label layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code is supported from iOS 2.0 up.